# Using SQL where condition more than once dynamically in Python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I created SQLite table called 'annotations' in python 3 where 'attribute' and 'feature' are  2 columns out of 10 columns. I want to select all rows when the following conditions exist.

def extract(gff_list, keyword, feature):
    # some other codes
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM annotations WHERE attribute LIKE ? AND 
    feature = ?", ('%'+ keyword +'%', feature),)

It doesn't work. I would be appreciated if you could modify the code.

Comment: Your code looks correct to me.  Please define what "doesn't work" means here.

Comment: It doesn't give me an error either doesn't retrieve those information which I know exists in the table. It stays calm

Comment: Then maybe add some sample data along with the raw query you are trying to execute.